# Add document for current user profile meteor.js

Tags: javascript, meteor

I want to create a form to add additional profile details (address, phone number) for registered users. 
This is my js file:

```
    Template.userProfileEdit.events({
    'submit form': function(event, template){
        event.preventDefault();
        var addressVar = template.find('#inputaddress');
        var profile = {};
        var fields = template.findAll('input[type="text"]');
        for(var i = 0; i<fields.length; i++) {
            profile[$(fields[i]).attr('name')] = $(fields[i]).val();
        }
        if(Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(), {$set: {profile: profile}})) {
            $(template.find('#thirdNodal')).modal('hide');
        }
    }
});

Template.userProfileEdit.helpers({
    address: function(){
        return Meteor.user().profile.address;
    }
});
Accounts.findUserByUsername = function (username) {
    return Accounts.findUserByQuery({
        username: username
    });
};
Accounts.findUserByEmail = function (email) {
    return Accounts.findUserByQuery({
        email: email
    });
};
```

And this is my html form:

```
<tr>
    <td>Address</td>
    <td>{{currentUser.profile.address}}</td>
</tr>
```

Does anybody know the easiest way how to insert(address) and update it? Or is it ok?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code doesn't work? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception, post the line it occurred on and the exception details.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't far from a working solution, but I see a couple issues.

`Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(), {$set: {profile: profile}})` is going to override the profile object, erasing anything already stored there. Also, giving the user client-side permissions to update a user document is a security disaster waiting to happen. Ideally you should make a call to a meteor method located in your server folder instead, so that you can keep your permissions tight by validating the changes on the server.

Second, if you utilize meteor's template system (blaze) you should hardly ever have to use jQuery selectors to retrieve values. Instead, look up HTML forms so that you can use Template events for easy access to form fields upon clicking a submit button.

You should complete the [Meteor tutorial](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/creating-an-app) which will provide you with all of this information and more.

Comment: "_Also, giving the user client-side permissions to update a user document is a security disaster waiting to happen._" I agree, but that's the default behaviour of `accounts`.

Comment: I was a little surprised, but [you're correct](http://joshowens.me/the-curious-case-of-the-unknowing-leaky-meteor-security/). OP, see link for fix.

Comment: Crazy, right? `profile` is a free-for-all by default. Note that your answer could be way more developed if OP actually told what went wrong with his current code piece, so you should generally comment on questions to ask for clarifications if there isn't enough.